# Bootstrap 3 checkbox center alignment and float: none seems to be ignored in IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

First of all here is the bootply sandbox: [demo of the issue](http://www.bootply.com/yvT2hjUU3p). It is rendered as expected in Chrome and FF, but `float: none` seems to be ignored in IE.

Steps:

The only thing I've added to the basic starter bootply template is the following markup:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <input id="myCheckbox" style="float: none;" type="checkbox">
  <label for="myCheckbox">My checkbox</label>
</div>
```

This div inside and original `<div class="text-center">` so all text *and* the checkbox are horizontally center aligned... *if* I apply the `float: none` to the input element.

The problem is that in only IE (all versions including 11) the `float: none` seems to be ignored, so the checkbox is still aligned to left, way far from its label. This issue was detected in a pretty complex page which used kendo, bootstrap, a custom bootstrap theme (inspinia) + some custom styles, but finally I've succeded to isolate it in this very simple bootstrap only demo.

In pictures:

Correct rendering in Chrome and FF:

[image]

Very same markup incorrect rendering in IE 11:

[image]

Missed I something? I would like to have the checkbox center aligned. Margins are not really option, because this page should be a responsive, and the container will be resized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not really sure why it works in Chrome and FF and not in IE, and which browser is "right" (probably not IE I'm guessing...), however the problem in IE is the `position: absolute` that the checkbox gets from the Boostrap CSS. So if you just add `position: relative` to the checkbox in addition to `float: none` it will be rendered as expected in IE as well.